# Count rows that meet certain requirements and then subtract that number from another count

Tags: tableau-api, level-of-detail

Let's say I have data like this:

| Type | OrderNumber | Priority | DeliveryMethod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Boxes | 1 | High | UPS |
| Misc | 1 | High | UPS |
| Boxes | 2 | Standard | InstaBox |
| Boxes | 3 | Standard | UPS |
| Boxes | 3 | Standard | UPS |
| Boxes | 3 | Standard | UPS |
| Boxes | 4 | Standard | Instabox |
| Boxes | 5 | Standard | Instabox |
| Boxes | 5 | Standard | Instabox |
| Boxes | 6 | Standard | UPS |
| Boxes | 7 | Standard | UPS |

And I want to count all the so called "Private Orders". They are boxes with an unique ordernumber and a Standard priority and UPS delivery.
(There's 2 in this example, 6 and 7)
Then I want to count all the boxes with Standard priority and subtract all the Private orders. (There's 9 boxes with Standard priority, minus the 2 Private orders = 7.)

Is that possible in Tableau? I want to display the number 7 in a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Private orders` use this field

```
IF 
{FIXED [Type], [Ordernumber] : COUNT([Ordernumber])} = 1
AND [Type] = 'Boxes' And [Priority] = 'Standard' And [DeliveryMethod] = 'UPS'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

For all boxes use this

```
Sum(
If [Type] = 'Boxes' And [Priority] = 'Standard' then 1 else 0 end
)
```

SO FOR FINAL OUTPUT YOU MAY USE THIS DIRECTLY say `calculation2`

```
Sum(
If [Type] = 'BOXES' And [Priority] = 'Standard' then 1 else 0 END
) -
Sum(IF 
{FIXED [Type], [OrderNumber] : COUNT([OrderNumber])} = 1
AND [Type] = 'BOXES' And [Priority] = 'Standard' And [DeliveryMethod] = 'UPS'
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

For matching pattern change the above field to say `calculation3`

```
Sum(
If [Type] = 'BOXES' And [Priority] = 'Standard' then 1 else 0 END
) -
Sum(IF 
{FIXED [Type], [OrderNumber] : COUNT([OrderNumber])} = 1
AND [Type] = 'BOXES' And [Priority] = 'Standard' And REGEXP_MATCH([DeliveryMethod], "UPS")
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

the data used

[image]

Results

[image]

Comment: Is this a calculated field? Then where do I put it? If I put it in the Marks area I get the result -6154. (6154 Is the total number of rows in the data.) The same happens if I put it in a column or row. I'm a beginner at Tableau.

Comment: Check it now please

Comment: It produced the same result. I checked the calculations separately and the first part is equal to 0 and the second part 6154. That's why it ends up as -6154.

Comment: Wait it works now. I changed ```[Type] = 'Boxes'``` to ```[Type] = 'BOXES'``` In the data that's how they are stored! Didn't know Caps where important. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait! There one more thing, would be really cool if you could answer. I want the ```[DeliveryMethod]```to contain the word UPS. How do I write that? I've played around with ```[CONTAINS]``` but don't understand how it works. Or is it possible to use a wildcard? Like ```[DeliveryMethod] = * + 'UPS' + *```